# Get pixel color via dos.h (turbo c++)

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

Im currently working on a project that requires me to draw things on screen without graphics.h, im working on DOSBOX (turbo c++).

The following function puts a pixel of color "color"(1-256) in x,y of the screen via an interrupt (dos.h):

```
void PutPixel(int x, int y, int color) {
    _AH = 0x0C;
    _AL = color;
    _CX = x;
    _DX = y;
    _BX = 0x01;
    geninterrupt (0x10);
}
```

What's the code of a function that returns the color of a pixel in x,y? I imagine something like:

```
type getPixel(int x, int y){
//code
return color;
}
```

Aditionally, could someone explain how PutPixel works? I know it modifies registers, but I dont know what each value means (besides _CX,_DX,_AL based on context).

Comment: Consider getting a modern compiler where you can actually write standards compliant C++.

Comment: Even a previous-century, 4-standard-releases-ago compiler would be better than this. If anywhere, this belongs on RetroComputing.SE, alongside Commodore64 and ZX84 questions.

Comment: the usage of turbo c++ and DOSBOX is a requirement given for the task, its intention is to emulate a really old computer. The project involves the making of a GUI from scratch (pixel by pixel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that `getPixel()` can be implemented like this:

```
int getPixel(int x, int y)
{
    _AH = 0x0D;
    _CX = x;
    _DX = y;
    _BX = 0x01;
    geninterrupt (0x10);
    return _AL;
}
```

These things work by calling code (interrupt handlers) that are stored in your computers BIOS.

You can read more about it in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H)